# How am I supposed to apply a match or Option after an unwrap?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get into Rust from a Python background and I'm having an issue with a PoC I'm messing around with.  I've read through a bunch of blogs and documentation on how to handle errors in Rust, but I can't figure out how to implement it when I use `unwrap` and get a panic.  Here is part of the code:

```
fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:5432").unwrap();

    // The .0 at the end is indexing a tuple, FYI
    loop {
        let stream = listener.accept().unwrap().0;
        stream.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_millis(100)));
        handle_request(stream);
    }
}

// Things change a bit in here
fn handle_request(stream: TcpStream) {
    let address = stream.peer_addr().unwrap();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);
    let mut payload = "".to_string();

    for line in reader.by_ref().lines() {
        let brap = line.unwrap();
        payload.push_str(&*brap);
        if brap == "" {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{0} -> {1}", address, payload);
    send_response(reader.into_inner());
}
```

It is handling the socket not receiving anything with `set_read_timeout` on the stream as expected, but when that triggers my `unwrap` on line in the loop it is causing a panic.  Can someone help me understand how I'm properly supposed to apply a match or `Option` to this code?

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a large disconnect here. `unwrap` or `expect` handle errors by panicking the thread. You aren't really supposed to "handle" a panic in 99.9% of Rust programs; you just let things die.

If you don't want a panic, don't use `unwrap` or `expect`. Instead, pass back the error via a `Result` or an `Option`, as described in the [Error Handling section of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html).

You can `match` (or any other pattern matching technique) on the `Result` or `Option` and handle an error appropriately for your case. One example of handling the error in your outer loop:

```
use std::net::{TcpStream, TcpListener};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:5432")
        .expect("Unable to bind to the port");

    loop {
        if let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept() {
            stream
                .set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_millis(100)))
                .expect("Unable to set timeout");

            handle_request(stream);    
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I **highly** recommend using `expect` instead of `unwrap` in just about every case.